# Run vue.js webpack-simple on cpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, cpanel, vuejs3

I've just finished my vue.js webpack-simple application to run on my cpanel shared hosting account. I've already tried:

1. I set build.js as my startup file, and uploaded the build.js file and build.js.map file
2. Uploading the whole script and running the dev js script

Both of the above didn't work.

Comment: you don't upload your source code to your web server like that, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html or https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/tooling/deployment.html#turn-on-production-mode

Comment: What hosting provider are you using? Good luck with cPanel... it's a nightmare for React and Vue apps :/. Since you don't have a backend, can't you just upload everything to the public folder and let Apache do the serving for you?